# adding initial entry to the ldap directory?

Tags: openldap

Trying to excute following command in openldap 2.4.42 for Windows and it says "Invalid format (line 8) entry: "cn=manager,dc=xxx,dc=com"

ldapmodify.exe -a -x -h localhost -p 389 -D "cn=manager,dc=xxx,dc=com" -f d:\OpenLDAP\ldifdata\step1.ldif -w secret

Here is ldif file

dn: dc=xxx,dc=com
dc: xxx
objectclass: dcobject
objectclass: organization
o: xxx company

dn: cn=manager,dc=xxx,dc=com
dc=xxx
objectclass: dcobject
objectclass: organization
cn=manager
sn: xjsy

In 2.4.42 version, there is no ldapadd.exe file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add the manager entry. It is already defined in the configuration. However you should be adding *other* manager entries into the DIT, with permissions defined in the config, for your admins and applications to use. Nobody should use the configured manager ID.